# What am i doing wrong in this Java optional - orElse statement

Tags: java, functional-programming, option-type

```
 List<String> list = 
  Arrays.asList("TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3");

    final String finalStr = 
Optional.ofNullable(list.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.contains("pattern:a:b:"))
            .map(str -> str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(':') + 1))
            .findFirst())
            .orElse(list.stream()
                    .filter(s -> !s.contains("pattern:c:d:"))
                    .findFirst())
            .orElseThrow();
```

It will work if the list contains pattern:a:b: but for above example always throw an exception if that pattern is not available. In the orElse part it doesnt even seem to be executing.

My result is
[java]     => java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present when i am epecting to return me the first element.

Edit: I wish to first find if any string with pattern:a:b exists in the list, if it does not, i wish it to return me the first string that does not contain the pattern:c:d For example

"pattern:a:b:TEST1", "pattern:c:d:TEST2", "TEST3" should always return TEST1.

"pattern:c:d:TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3" should always return TEST2.

"TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3" should always return TEST1.

Comment: With `java.util.Optional`, this doesn't even compile. Are you using some other implementation?

Comment: I just ran it and it gave me the      [java]     => java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present exception

Comment: It doesnt seem to be going into the orElse part,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow the evaluation. Since the inner part of the `Optional.ofNullable(...)` results in `Optional<String>`, the entire chain wraps it in `Optional<Optional<String>>`.

After evaluation of the parameter in `Optional.ofNullable(...)`, the result is roughly this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(Optional.<String>empty())      // Optional<Optional<String>>
                .orElse(list.stream().findFirst()) // Optional<String>
                .orElseThrow();                    // String
```

The `orElse` is **not** called as long as the `Optional.empty()` is not `null`, hence the outer `Optional` is **not empty**. The flow continues with the inner `Optional.enpty` on which the `orElseThrow` is called and always fails by throwing `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

What you want to do is this:

```
final String finalStr = list.stream()                        // Stream<String>
        .filter(s -> s.contains("pattern:a:b:"))             // Stream<String>
        .map(str -> str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(':') + 1)) // Stream<String>
        .findFirst()                                         // Optional<String>
        .or(() -> list.stream().findFirst())                 // Optional<String>
        .orElseThrow();                                      // String
```

The `or` method is the key one as on empty `Optional<T>` it supplies with a different one without losing the `Optional<T>` context.

Answer (score 2):

Your misunderstanding is that `findFirst` returns null if the stream is empty, and tries to use `Optional.ofNullable` to wrap it into an `Optional`. `findFirst` in fact returns an `Optional<T>` directly, so you end up with a double optional - `Optional<Optional<String>>`. And the outer optional is never empty, since `findFirst` always returns a non-null value (that could be either an empty or a non-empty `Optional`).

Then, you use `orElse` on it. Since the outer optional is never empty, this always unwraps the outer optional and the default value you provide is never used. Finally, `orElseThrow` is called on the inner optional, which could be empty or non-empty, as that is what is returned by the first `findFirst`. If it happens to be empty, you'd get the exception.

You should not wrap the first `findFirst` in `Optional.ofNullable` in the first place. Use [`or`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) to supply another `Optional` as the alternative when the optional is empty.

```
final String finalStr =
    list.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.contains("pattern:a:b:"))
            .map(str -> str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(':') + 1))
            .findFirst()
        .or(() ->
            list.stream()
                .filter(s -> !s.contains("pattern:c:d"))
                .findFirst()
        )
        .orElseThrow();
```